# Can a single fast be used for multiple purposes?

Tags: fast-days, tractate-brachot

Brachos daf 31b says that one who fasts on Shabbos should fast another day to atone for his fast. Suppose the next day is a previously ordained fast (e.g 17th of Tammuz, etc.), does that fast count to atone for his Shabbos fast, or must he fast another day?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105704/16706

Comment: There is something which might be relevant about not having one fast for two purposes in [Ta'anit 8b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Taanit.8b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)